# android change the image of image button with the same size

Tags: android

I have an image button and I am trying to do a simple thing which is changing the image of image button when I click it, I did this and it worked but I faced a little problem which is when the image change the new image is bigger than the old image and I need to know how I can make the new image size the same is the old one.

[here is the difference between the old image and the new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjck0.png)

here is my code:

```
    final ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSound);
    currentImage = R.drawable.s_on;

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            currentImage = (currentImage == R.drawable.s_on) ? R.drawable.s_off : R.drawable.s_on;
            btn2.setImageResource(currentImage);
            
        }
    });




    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImgBtnEmail"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:background="@drawable/email"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.024" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
btn2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
btn2.setImageResource(currentImage);
```

Comment: thanks for the replay I tried your code but still the same issue

Comment: can you share your xml code? And 2 images?

Comment: I added the xml code and the 2 images are in the link

Comment: I get the problem the reason is I changed the image size in xml and when I change the image it return it to the original size so I need to change the size of the new image programmaticaly

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the size of the image programmatically:

```
btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));
```